# How to find DNS Server of particular internal IP(different domain) address?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, windows-server, subnet

I have two windows domains (A.com, B.com).

I want to find DNS server of B.com from A.com.

I know domain controller ip of B.com.

How can i find the DNS server of B.com using that dc ip address from A.com (dc ip of domain --> dns server of that domain)?

Packets can be transferred from A.com to B.com and visaversa. (ping,tracert,nslookup,etc working between these domains)

Comment: I need to find dns server programmatically. its hard to make setup like solution given by AirCombat in all client machines. Can you please tell some command or api for finding this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this, I recommend creating a forward lookup zone for B.com and adding the records OR changing the NS and SOA records to that of 'DC1.B.COM.'